# React - How to get child component's position in ancestor component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to get a child component position in a tree in my React app to make a 'tour/guide' for my application. if it was vanilla js, I was able to easily get the target node using document.querySelector() but since in react we have to use **refs** to get access to the element, and it's not a good way to use **refForward** in many child components to approach the target one from the **grand parent** component, what is the best solution to get properties of a child component in a tree?

I think one possible solution is saving target elements' position in a global state manager like *context* or *redux*, but since the position is changing frequently, it would cause some critical **performance** issues in the app.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Couldn't you inject that position from the parent component through a prop?

Comment: @MinusFour consider it as a grand grand parent :) I think it's not a good way to pass it in multiple layers to reach the target component.

Comment: @PouyaJabbarisani : Would you please show us your effort for the particular case :) That you have tried so far ? `I think one possible solution is saving target elements' position in a global state ` .. Better trying implementing it rather than just thinking ;) Try it , and if you get stuck come with you code and we will take it from there :) CHEERS

Comment: You can still use `document.querySelector`. Just assign proper `id` or use a specific class name in your components.

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather position is a dynamic thing and changes in every moment, there are some ways to catch and save in context but the app will crash because of a huge process over the components. I even tried to save ref in the context to have access to the position using ref. but it not worked.

Comment: ` position is a dynamic thing and changes in every moment,` Could you please elaborate on this ? May be you are getting the position dynamically on a particular action ! Is it so ?

Comment: @Sohaib actually I'm thinking about that, but as I remember, it's somehow forbidden in react 

Comment: Where did you read that? As long as you call `document.querySelector` after your components are rendered, it should be fine.

Comment: @Sohaib explained in here: https://blog.cloudboost.io/using-ref-in-react-a832fa3a5125 I think there should be a good solution in react for this situation, but if I can't find any I have to use this. thank you for your help.